# Javafx Checker game

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop, click

I am required to make a checker game using javafx, player v player. I can build the board but I cannot for the life of me figure out where to go from there. My sppecific problem is getting the pieces to move. I've looked at HelloDragAndDrop but it's of no help. I've been searching for hours and cannot find a helpful starting point. I am by no means asking for someone to finish the code for me, but rather a start as to the direction i should head, because I'm just lost. Thanks.

I've added a method to drag and drop which detects a drag and a drop but doesn't actually move the checker. Any help?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Cell;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CheckerboardSetUp extends Application{
private static final int BOARD_DIM = 8;
private static final int SQUARES = 64;
private static final int PIECES = 12;
private Cell[][] boardG = new Cell[8][8];
private Circle[] p1p = new Circle[12];
private Circle[] p2p = new Circle[12];
private GridPane board = new GridPane();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    buildBoard(board);
    putSquaresOnBoard(board);
    putPiecesOnBoard(board,p1p,p2p);
    intializeListeners();
    board.setPadding(new Insets(15,15,15,15));
    Scene scene = new Scene(board, 700, 700);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Checkers");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void intializeListeners() {
    for (int i = 0; i < PIECES; i++){
        p1p[i].setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                for(int i = 0; i < PIECES; i++){
                Dragboard db = p1p[i].startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putString("Hello");
                db.setContent(content);
                System.out.println("setOnDragDetected");
            }}
        });
        board.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent e){
                e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
                System.out.println("dragOverDetected");
            }
        });
        board.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent e){
                e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
                System.out.println("dropDetected");
            }
        });
    }

}

private void buildBoard(GridPane board){
    for(int i = 0; i < BOARD_DIM; i++){
    RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
    rc.setMinHeight(SQUARES);
    rc.setMaxHeight(SQUARES);
    rc.setPrefHeight(SQUARES);
    rc.setValignment(VPos.CENTER);
    board.getRowConstraints().add(rc);

    ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
    cc.setMinWidth(SQUARES);
    cc.setMaxWidth(SQUARES);
    cc.setPrefWidth(SQUARES);
    cc.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
    board.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
    }
}
private void putSquaresOnBoard(GridPane board) {
    Color[] sqColors = new Color[]{Color.RED, Color.BLACK};
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_DIM; i ++){
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_DIM; j++){
            board.add(new Rectangle(SQUARES,SQUARES,sqColors[(i+j)%2]),i,j);
        }
    }
}   

private void putPiecesOnBoard(GridPane board, Circle[] p1p, Circle[] p2p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < PIECES; i++){
        p1p[i] = new Circle(SQUARES/2-4, Color.AZURE);
        p1p[i].setStroke(Color.CORAL);
        board.add(p1p[i], i % (BOARD_DIM / 2) * 2 + (2 * i / BOARD_DIM) % 2, 
                BOARD_DIM - 1 - (i * 2) / BOARD_DIM);

        p2p[i] = new Circle(SQUARES/2-4, Color.CORAL);
        p2p[i].setStroke(Color.AZURE);
        board.add(p2p[i], i % (BOARD_DIM / 2) * 2 + (1 + 2 * i / BOARD_DIM) % 2, 
                (i * 2) / BOARD_DIM);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: May be this can help you http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/HelloDragAndDrop.java.html

Comment: Could you explain in your question where exactly you are stuck? What is the concrete problem that you are facing?

Comment: I edited to add my question. I can't figure out how to get the pieces to move. I've looked at HelloDragAndDrop but it's of no help.